# I can't simulate slow printing, always ends in error

Tags: python

### I have tried these solutions

```
for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    time.sleep(.1)
print(letter, end='')
```

---

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 50 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
    print ''
```

---

```
import sys,time

def sprint(str):
   for c in str + '\n':
     sys.stdout.write(c)
     sys.stdout.flush()
     time.sleep(3./90)

sprint('hello world')
```

---

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

print_slow("Type whatever you want here")
```

---

And they all give the same result:

> TypeError: sprint()/print()/slowprint()/print_slow() takes 1
> positional argument but 2 were given

### here is the part of code that always jam:

```
print('kort 1: ', kort_1)
print('Kort 2: ', kort_2)
print('Summa: ', summa )
```

---

I have spent close to 10 hours just searching, but i have found no awnser that works with my code.
:(

Comment: how do you call your functions? judging from the error message with more than one argument. but you have defined them to accept one argument only.

Comment: ```print("STR", var)``` will fail. You need to do ```print("STR"+str(var))```

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable's name - it's a reserved word. Also, `print ""` must read `print("")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were close multiple times. Looking at your error i think something in your calling of your own functions is not lining up with the way you intend to use it.

Because this works on my side:

```
import time

def printSlow(toPrint):
    for letter in toPrint:
        print(letter, end='')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        

printSlow("Hello")
```

Which is very similar to the various versions you've tried.