# Want to print multiple times in single line Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program which outputs the text as if it is typed live. For that, I am printing a word and waiting for 0.2 seconds and then other.

I have saw this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-print-in-same-line-in-python
But the thing is print() keeps on collecting the characters that are to be printed and then flush them after the loop is over. So I am not able to get the result that I want.

This is the code:

```
import time

time.sleep(2)

welcome = "Welcome. We will plot a graph in this program"

for i in range(len(welcome)):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(welcome[i], end="")
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't simulate slow printing, always ends in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495438/i-cant-simulate-slow-printing-always-ends-in-error)

It's weird, i just tried the example I used to answer this question, but it isn't working anymore. It definitely worked before, or else i wouldn't have answered that question. I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Regarding my own comment; I think i tested the above example in an older python installation. As the `flush=True` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3 you can use `flush=True`:

```
for character in welcome:
    print(character, end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

I made the code clearer by replacing `for i in range(len(welcome))` by `for word in welcome`, so you just have to print `character`.

Comment: Like this answer more.

Comment: To make it more "life-like" `import random` then `time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05, 0.5))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush standard output because you don't use '\n' at the end of your string.

```
import sys
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import time


time.sleep(2)

welcome = "Welcome. We will plot a graph in this program"

for i in range(len(welcome)):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(welcome[i], end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Better explaination [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sys-stdout-flush/).

Another one : [Usage of sys.stdout.flush() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method)

Comment: Thanks for resolving the problem and giving the required explanation.

Comment: I got another way to flush it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function It is more simple and it doesn't need sys module